# How to make a Tkinter label update?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple tkinter GUI with a label displaying a number and a button. I have it set to the variable x, and when button is pushed, the value of x goes up by one. However, when I hit the button, the label doesn't update. How do I do this?

```
from tkinter import *

x = 1
def add():
    global x
    x += 1

win = Tk()

label = Label(win, text=x)
label.pack()

button = Button(win, text="Increment", command=add)
button.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Integers are *immutable*, when you do `x += 1` you assign *a new object* to `x`, while the `Label` still points to the old one (well, sort of...). Either explicitly update `l` from `add` or use an `IntVar` for `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuring the `text` of a label is a one shot effect. Updating the int later won't update the label.

To solve this, you can either explicitly update the label yourself:

```
def add():
    global x
    x += 1
    label.configure(text=x)
```

... Or you can use a [tkinter variable](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) like an `IntVar` (or more generally, a `StringVar`, if your text isn't just a number), which *does* update the label when you update the var. Don't forget to configure `textvariable` instead of `text` if you do this.

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

x = IntVar()
x.set(1)
def add():
    x.set(x.get() + 1)

label = Label(win, textvariable=x)
label.pack()

button = Button(win, text="Increment", command=add)
button.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Take care to create a `Tk()` instance *before* you create the `IntVar`, otherwise tkinter will throw an exception.

Comment: You don't need `textvariable`.

Comment: I know. My first solution doesn't use `textvariable`, but my second one does.

Comment: I'm planning to use this question as a duplicate target in the future, so I made some changes to the question and your answer. Feel free to rollback everything if you don't like the edits.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it manually by associating a `command` with the click of the button. Suppose you want the text of the `Label` to update when you click `button`:

```
button = Button(win, text="One", command=add) # add() is called when button is clicked
```

Now, you define the `add` command/function in order to change the text in the label:

```
def add():
    global x
    x += 1
    label.config(text=x) # calling the method config() to change the text
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did is to use a IntVar() and a method to add or subtract:

```
*outside the class body*
def plus1(self,var,l):
    var.set(int(var.get())+1)
    l.textvariable = var
    return var.get()

*Inside the body of your class*
self.your_text = IntVar()
self.your_text.set(0)

self.l = Label(master, textvariable = (self.your_text))
self.plus_n = Button(root,text = '+',command=lambda : self.your_text.set(self.plus1(self.your_text,self.l) )
```

This is how I did it and it works for me, probably there are more elegant ways to solve the problem