# Is there any way to make a label in Tkiner forget its data?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Hello guys I want to make a phishing python program ( For educational purposes ) ! 
 
It's something I want to show to my class and my classmates. 
Anyways, I want that function to show the data into the label for just a few seconds and then dissapear like I never called it. 
Thank you in advance !

```
def sel():
    varl = ["Profile Hacking","Page Hacking","See who's watching your profile"]
    selection = '"'+varl[var.get()]+'" Option activated !'
    label = Label(root,text=selection)
    label.grid(row=6,column=0)
```

Comment: There are several ways, it depends on what you mean by "forget". You can set the label value to an empty string, you can  hide the label widget, or you can destroy the label widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this link it poses a similar question to yours:[How to make a Label appear then disappear after a certain amount of time in python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276672/how-to-make-a-label-appear-then-disappear-after-a-certain-amount-of-time-in-pyth)

The answer in this link uses the .after() method where you can either un pack the label widget after a given time or destroy it. He also shows a coded example.

You can also check out this link which will allow you to update the labels text and using the .after() method you can to do this either after a event or x amount of time :[How to make a Tkinter label update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303346/how-to-make-a-tkinter-label-update)

Good luck and have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mgracer, 
but your idea didn't help me fix my problem. 
This line did :

```
 root.after(2000, label.destroy)
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
 label.grid_remove()
 root.after(3000, label.destroy)
```

this should destroy the label

```
label = None
del label
```

but if you don't want to get rid of the label you do this:

```
label = Label(root,text='')
label.grid(row=6, column=0
```

Comment: @Kostas Petrakis may I ask what the code did for you and how both didn't work it will help me with my coding :)

Comment: you should never use `sleep` in a GUI (unless it's running in a different thread). There's also no good reason to put it in an arbitrarily huge row and column.

Comment: Whats the alternative to use for sleep and to set the grid to outside the window? Im guessing the after thing?

Comment: The alternative to sleep depends on what you are trying to accomplish.As for grid, just use `grid_remove` or `grid_forget` if you want to keep the widget but remove it from view. Note: `after(3)` is the same as `sleep`, and you shouldn't do it. It causes the entire GUI to freeze.

Comment: Is that a better answer? :)

Comment: No, now you have a syntax error in your `after` example, plus you're simply using it wrong. It needs to be `root.after(3000, label.destroy)`. You should also mention it does more than just "set the label out the window". It does more than that -- it destroys the label.